# Android exit with toast

Tags: android, android-toast

I have a `quit()` method that I am using. I use a toast to print out "thank you for using this app". On the next line I do a `system.exit(0);` and when I run the app, the toast doesn't show before the system exits the app. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: why do you use System.exit(0) in the first place ? Just call Finish for all your activities and show the Toast in the onStop method.

Comment: how would this be written

Comment: Please do not provide "exit" functions and please do not show "thank you for using" messages.  They are anti-Android and really annoy users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you should do it, in your activity:

```
Toast.makeText(this,"Thanks for using the app",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
finish();
```

Forget System.exit

Comment: so the finish(); completely exits the app?  What if i wanted to go the the home screen on the phone and leave the app running?

Comment: `finish()` destroys your *current* activity. @JustinEsders

Comment: Thanks. This will close your app but your Toast will still show.

Answer (score 1):

You could run a thread that waits for the duration of your `Toast`.-

```
Thread thread = new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(WAIT_TIME_IN_MILLIS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
    }
};

thread.start();
```